# Menu items centered on screen when clicking on 'menu', with fading background and border effect

Tags: javascript, css, menu, hover, menuitem

So I just came across the site of http://www.dennisadelmann.de/

I want to recreate something similiar like his menu. So when I hover on it there is a black border, and when I click on it the screen fades to black with menu items centered on the screen. I tried to figure out how he got this working, but it's quite difficult. I couldn't find anything in a javascript file.
I noticed in the html his menu code is dynamic when clicked on it.

I'm just a beginner with javascript so that make things alot harder of course. At least I assume it's done with javascript..

I don't know where to search for in the internet, so maybe if this kind of menu has a specific name I can search for a tutorial?

If not..is it hard to recreate a menu like this?

Many thanks!

Below an example of his menu item in HTML in default state:

```
<div class="menu_overlay" style="display: none;">
            <div class="close"><a>Close</a></div>
            <div class="links_hover">
                <p class="work_in" style="opacity: 0;">7 projects online</p>
                <p class="about_in" style="opacity: 0;">About Dennis Adelmann</p>
                <p class="journal_in" style="opacity: 0;">The digital sketchbook</p>
                <p class="contact_in" style="opacity: 0;">Get in touch</p>
            </div>
            <div class="links_wrapper">
                <ul class="links_overlay">
                    <li><a class="work" href="portfolio.php">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a class="about" href="about.php">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="journal" href="journal.php">Sketchbook</a></li>
                    <li><a class="contact" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <header>
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="right"></div>
            <div id="top"></div>
            <div id="bottom"></div>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="links">
                        <li><a>Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>
```

And when clicked on the menu item, the one thing that is changing is:

```
<div class="menu_overlay" style="display: block;">
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? provide html and css at least.

Comment: No, it's not difficult. But you really have to try something. Try to imagine what's happening: all you have to do is catching some events, and then...

Comment: see http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple example how it can be done. ( there is only a structure )
There is no code quality but I think you can improove it, here's all magic made by **javascript**:

```
var $menu = $( '.menu' );
var $body = $( 'body' );
var $nav = $( '.navigation' );
var $close = $( '.close' );

$menu.on('mouseover', function(){

  $body.addClass( 'hovered' );
});

$menu.on('mouseleave', function(){

  $body.removeClass( 'hovered' );
});

$menu.on( 'click', function(){

  $body.addClass( 'open' );
})

$close.on( 'click', function(){

  $body.removeClass( 'open' );
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">Menu</div>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="close">Close</div>  
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem a distinctio porro nulla vitae, id modi alias earum eos rerum quasi natus qui sunt, libero! Impedit, at. Accusantium, perferendis quod.
  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
  padding: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px transparent;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body.hovered {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #000;
}
body .navigation {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  color: #fff;
}
body.open .navigation {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

All working example you can find here:
http://codepen.io/GomatoX/pen/WbGLmd

Comment: Thank you so much man!! Exactly what I needed :D Its a shame I don't know javascript well..Im still learning this. I tried to upvote you..but my reputation is too low..

Answer (score 0):

[**see fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jvyx2rm/)

```
$('.link').click(function () {
    $('.overlay').fadeIn();
});
$('.close').click(function () {
    $('.overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

**css**

```
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
.link {
    float:right;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#000;
    margin-top:50px;
}
.close {
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your anwser in combination with GomatoX his anwser is exactly what I was searching for! :) I can't upvote you though..my rep is too low.